# Changing which command line program runs when there are two programs with the same name

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, java, command-line-arguments

When I run `where java`, the output is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe
```

Both of these programs are called 'java', but the one on top runs by default. How can I change the default to be the lower one, so that when I type `java` (program) it uses the `java` program from JDK, not from Java SE?

Comment: Follow [these instructions](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for editing your Windows environment variables and switch the entry order (or simply delete the first one i.e. the non-JDK entry).

Comment: Just edit your environment variable path .Remove one from the path then close command prompt and open it again. type  `set` to view the path in which `cmd` will look when you execute any command.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Without any edit `%PATH%`  system variable:

Use `|find "string"`...

```all-bat
>where java|find/i "jdk"  
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe
```

---

Here is one `.bat` file to find `\jdk*\java.exe` and using...

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem :: check *sdk\java.exe x86, 64 and W6432 variable :: 
for %%i in (ProgramFiles,ProgramFiles(x86^),ProgramW6432
)do if /i defined %%~i for /f tokens^=* %%z in ('2^>nul ^^^< nul ^^^
where /r "!%%~i!" java.exe^|find "jdk"')do set "_java=%%~z" && goto=%:^)

rem :: one simple error message if jdk*\java was not found ::
echo=jdk*\java.exe was not found in %%path%% variable and nor in...
echo=%%ProgramFiles%% ^| %%ProgramFiles(x86)%% ^| ^%%ProgramW6432%%

<con: rem./ & timeout.exe /t -1 /nobreak & endlocal & goto=%:eof

%:^)
rem./ your "jdk*\bin\java.exe" = !_java!
<con: rem./ & "!_java!" -version 2>&1|find/v ")" 
<con: rem./ & timeout.exe 5 & endlocal & goto=%:eof
```

---

---

**2)** Editing/change `%PATH%` system variable:

**1.** Remove from `%PATH%`

```all-bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

**2.** Add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin`

**3.** To do **1.** & **2.** in your command line:

```all-bat
set "variable"  =   %Variable:   item 1 == item 2%
set "variable"  =   %Variable:   item 1 == item 2%

set "PATH=%PATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin%"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [DOS Tips Substrings Operator](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

  - [`var:item=other_item`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), [`var:remove_item=`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), ...
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)